# Saving a base64 code into a folder gives me a failed image and cannot open it with PHP

Tags: php, image, curl, download, save

I am trying to save an image into a folder of my project, and file is saved but wrong, making it impossible to see or open.

**First of all, I get the image through a form where base64 image code is captured, after picking it. And then, when I submit the post, I go with this code:**

`var selectFotoAdjunta = document.getElementById("fotoAdjunta__url_val"); var selectedFotoAdjunta = selectFotoAdjunta.src; var selectedEncodedFotoAdjunta = encodeURIComponent(selectedFotoAdjunta);`

**And then, I send variable through the post system:**

`var $form = $( this ), $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ), fotoadjunta_value = selectedEncodedFotoAdjunta, url = $form.attr('action');`

```
    var posting = $.post( url, { 
        foto: fotoadjunta_value,
     });
```

**Then I go to my PHP code selected for the form, reached it correctly at first.**

Variable base64 code seems like this: *"data%3Aimage%2Fjpeg%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANS..."*
Complete base64 encoded image is here: https://justpaste.it/ft5rd

```
$extension = "jpeg";
if (!empty($foto)){
    $base64img = rawurldecode($foto);
    
    if (str_contains($base64img, 'data:image/jpeg')) { 
        $extension = "jpeg";
        $base64img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', "", $base64img);
        
    } else if (str_contains($base64img, 'data:image/jpg')) {
        $extension = "jpg";
        $base64img = str_replace('data:image/jpg;base64,', "", $base64img);
        
    } else if (str_contains($base64img, 'data:image/png')) {
        $extension = "png";
        $base64img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', "", $base64img);
    } 
    
    $filename = '../Imagenes/temp_viajes.'.$extension;
    $fpc = file_put_contents($filename, $base64img);
        if ($fpc) { echo 'Image uploaded correctly'; }

}
```

But when I go to the folder with the image, i get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK0Kv.png)

I tried too, to use base64_decode function instead of rawurldecode, but anyway is the same.
Could you help me with this? I don't know what is happening, sincerely.

I tried to download the image into a local folder, but couldn't do it correctly.

Comment: FYI: `$base64img = rawurldecode($foto);` - that only became necessary, because you are sending a value that has been URL-encoded _twice_. PHP will automatically decode one "level" of URL encoding in the received GET / POST parameters. `$.post()` on the client side will automatically take care of URL-encoding the parameters - but you also applied URL encoding to the value yourself, `var selectedEncodedFotoAdjunta = encodeURIComponent(selectedFotoAdjunta);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image data you are trying to store is base64-encoded. You correctly URL-Decoded and stripped the `data` prefix, but missed the `base64_decode` part.

Try changing your second last line to:

```php
$fpc = file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($base64img));
```

Please note that you should perform additional validation for any data coming from the user or a form as it is easy to exploit it.

Comment: Was just that the problem. Solved, thanks!